# backfill data when creating new microservice

Tags: message-queue, microservices

Given a microservice system using queues (sqs/sns or rabbitmq for example). 
And services for example:

- A create book service, where you create books, and you can edit them until you have published them. This service has a datastore with all books created, and publishes a message when a book has been published.
- A lending service, where users can lend a book. This service reads messages from create book service to know what books exists. It stores all loans and send a message when a book is loaned and returned.

This has been running for a while.
We now want to create a new service, showing statisitcs for loans.
It will listen to the create book service messages to get information about the books.
It will listen to the lending service to gather statistics.

What is the best practises to get data about books that was created before the statistics service into this new service? Since it is not using Kafka or similar data is not availible in the queue. It is only in the datastore of the create book service.

Comment: If you were using event sourcing, you could simply re-publish all events ever. However, if not then I don't see any practical way of achieving backfilling with messaging. You should probably design some kind of ETL to run when you go live.